# How to select a dropdown element on a website using javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I am writting a javascript program that needs to be able to select an element on a dropdown and then continue browsing. My problem is that even though I can select a dropdown element and that I can see the dropdown change on the website, the element I have selected doesn't seem to be "registered" and when I continue my browsing, the dropdown is back to the default option.

I figured out that maybe the website needs a mouse click to register the change so I have tried clicking on the dorpdown after selecting the right option but it still doesn't work.

Here is the different codes I have tried and which seems to both have the same problem :

```
//first try:
document.getElementById('SingleOptionSelector-0').selectedIndex = 2;
//second try :
document.getElementById('SingleOptionSelector-0').value = '3';
```

I tried to click on the dropdown menu like this:

```
document.getElementById('SingleOptionSelector-0').click();
```

But it doesn't expand. It's like the click is not registered which seems very strange to me because when I click somewhere else on the web-page it works just fine

I have seen a lot of questions about how to interact with a dropdown menu,but no one else seems to have the problem that when you change the value it is not registered by the web-page

The relevant HTML is below:

```
<select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-product-template_original product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-0" data-index="option1">
        <option value="1">Hamburger</option>
        <option value=" 2">fries</option>
        <option value="3">Coke</option>
        <option value="4">Diet Coke</option>
    </select>
```

edit : It seems that I was not clear enough. An example of my problem is the website https://www.xhibition.co/collections/air-jordan/products/jordan-23-engineered-full-zip-jacket?variant=29510378848328 . When I use one of these methods to change the "size" dropdown, I can see it changing but when going to the basket, the size of the element I just added is the default one ('M'). That's what I mean by the website "not registering" the dropdown change.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes the HTML you're attempting to interact with? Would you also mind elaborating on why you've tagged [tag:c#]?

Comment: It was a mistake, I shouldn't  have tagged c#. I edited my post to correct it. Here is the HTML code I'm trying to interract with : <select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-product-template_original product-form__input"
 id="SingleOptionSelector-0" data-index="option1"><option value="1">Hamburger</option><option value="
 2">fries</option><option value="3">Coke</option><option value="3">Diet Coke</option></select> @esqew

Comment: I can't re-produce this with an [immaterially-modified version of your example](https://repl.it/@esqew/OffbeatEnchantedDoom). Are the Javascript snippets you've provided exact copies of the snippets you're using in your attempt? They are targeting an `id` that does not exist in your HTML sample.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haved modified the ids so the whole code should now be consistent. @esqew

Comment: What do you mean it's not "registered"?

Comment: @xszn [My example](https://repl.it/@esqew/OffbeatEnchantedDoom) still cannot re-produce the behavior (or lack thereof) you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
document.getElementById('myDropDown').value = "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of vague, but I think the sample below should give you a good idea of how to get and set `select` element values and also how to use `addEventListener` to know when a `change` event has taken place:

```js
const selectEl0 = document.querySelector('#SingleOptionSelector-0');
const selectEl1 = document.querySelector('#SingleOptionSelector-1');
const onChange = e => selectEl1.value = e.target.value;
selectEl0.addEventListener('change', onChange)
```

```html
The second select element will update it's value when the first one changes:<br/>
<select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-product-template_original product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-0" data-index="option1">
  <option value="1">Hamburger</option>
  <option value="2">fries</option>
  <option value="3">Coke</option>
  <option value="4">Diet Coke</option>
</select>

<select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-product-template_original product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-1" data-index="option1">
  <option value="1">Hamburger</option>
  <option value="2">fries</option>
  <option value="3">Coke</option>
  <option value="4">Diet Coke</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my problem well. I edited my question in order to be more specific and added some informations. @Tom